# NestJS unit test with Jest and need to mock Http request that is injected in service

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I am working on NestJS project with Typescript.  I have read [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider) document of NestJS and followed it to inject a `Request` object in my service:

In my service class:

```
import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {}

  getClientUserAgent = ()=> {
     return this.request.headers['user-agent'];
  }
}
```

As you can see above, I have a function `getClientUserAgent()` which simply return the user-agent header via the injected `request`.

Now, I would like to Jest test this class.  I wonder what is the best way to mock a `request` object that could inject to `MyService` in my jest test?

I managed to instantiate an `MyService` object via the `testModule` in test now, so main question is about mocking a request object:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';

describe('My service', () => {
   let testModule: TestingModule;
   let myService: MyService;

   beforeAll(async () => {
     testModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
       imports: [...],
       providers: [MyService],
     }).compile();

    // myService from testModule
    myService = await testModule.resolve(MyService);
  });

   it('returns client user-agent', () => {
       // how to mock a request object that inject to MyService so that I can 
       // inject http headers with values I define for testing purpose?
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test my answer right now, but probably this will help you:

in `providers` where you are creating Testing Module, add this:

```
{
  provide: REQUEST,
  useValue: Request,
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work!

Also check this repo:

https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs

Comment: Thanks, but how to use that `Request` to inject headers?

Comment: In that case you should create a factory and mock the output value everytime! read the docs for `useFactory`

Comment: No, I understand what factory is in test, factory doesn't do injection. My question is how to inject a request object to my service during a test run, point here is injection. It would be nice if you could show that.